# Possible explanations for why my server became unresponsive

Tags: linux, filesystems

Right before my server became unresponsive for a couple minutes, I found the following log lines which seem related. I'm hoping to get a better understanding of what they mean and under what conditions they would happen:

```
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver journal: Runtime journal is using 776.0M (max allowed 793.9M, trying to leave 1.1G free of 6.9G available → current limit 793.9M).
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver journal: Runtime journal is using 776.0M (max allowed 793.9M, trying to leave 1.1G free of 6.9G available → current limit 793.9M).
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: INFO: task in:imjournal:2125 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: in:imjournal    D ffff88042bd2b8c8     0  2125      1 0x00000080
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: ffff88041bfdfdb8 0000000000000082 ffff88042be0bec0 ffff88041bfdffd8
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: ffff88041bfdffd8 ffff88041bfdffd8 ffff88042be0bec0 ffff88042be0bec0
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: ffff88042bd2b8b8 ffff88042bd2b8c0 ffffffff00000000 ffff88042bd2b8c8
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: Call Trace:
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: [<ffffffff8168c7f9>] schedule+0x29/0x70
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: [<ffffffff8168dfa5>] rwsem_down_write_failed+0x115/0x220
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: [<ffffffff81327647>] call_rwsem_down_write_failed+0x17/0x30
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: [<ffffffff812a84c0>] ? cap_mmap_addr+0x60/0x60
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: [<ffffffff8168b9bd>] down_write+0x2d/0x30
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: [<ffffffff811a07fc>] vm_mmap_pgoff+0x8c/0xe0
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: [<ffffffff811b62d6>] SyS_mmap_pgoff+0x116/0x270
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: [<ffffffff8102fb82>] SyS_mmap+0x22/0x30
Aug 25 18:23:32 myserver kernel: [<ffffffff81697809>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Here is some info regarding my server if it's helpful:

Centos 7.3 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 4 15:04:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Quad core with 16GB ram
- 2TB Soft RAID drives

Comment: I found this link that has some hints as well: http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/INFO:_task_blocked_for_more_than_120_seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article on the performance impact of using imjournal:
http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imjournal.html

Especially this part:

> Warning: Some versions of systemd journal have problems with database corruption, which leads to the journal to return the same data endlessly in a tight loop. This results in massive message duplication inside rsyslog probably resulting in a denial-of-service when the system ressouces get exhausted. This can be somewhat mitigated by using proper rate-limiters, but even then there are spikes of old data which are endlessly repeated. By default, ratelimiting is activated and permits to process 20,000 messages within 10 minutes, what should be well enough for most use cases. If insufficient, use the parameters described below to adjust the permitted volume. It is strongly recommended to use this plugin only if there is hard need to do so.

In short I think you should consider using imuxsock.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I was hoping to get a better understanding of what's causing the issue at a lower level.  Is the imjournal the actual problem or a indication of a different IO related problem?